# Cannot connect to Rabbitmq using SSL

Tags: ssl, scrapy, rabbitmq

I have been trying to connect to `Rabbitmq` via `SSL`.
The steps I followed are as below:

1. Generated certificates and pem file on server using [tls-gen](https://github.com/michaelklishin/tls-gen)

   Files generated were as follows:

   - server_key.pem
   - server_certificate.pem
   - client_key.pem
   - client_certificate.pem
   - ca_key.pem
   - ca_certificate.pem
2. Following this link [enabling ssl rabbitmq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html#enabling-ssl), I have created a file called `rabbitmq.config` under `/etc/rabbitmq`, copied a default configuration file and un-commented the lines:

   `[
   {rabbit, [
    {tcp_listeners, [5671]},
    {ssl_listeners, [5672]},
    {auth_mechanisms, ['EXTERNAL','PLAIN']},
    {ssl_options, [{cacertfile,"/path/to/ca_certificate.pem"},
                   {certfile,"/path/to/server_certificate.pem"},
                   {keyfile,"/path/to/server_key.pem"},
                   {verify,verify_peer},
                   {fail_if_no_peer_cert,false}]}
   ]}
   ].`
3. I have copied the client keys to the machine I am trying to connect to rabbitmq from and am using the following paramters:

   `RABBITMQ_CONNECTION_PARAMETERS = {'host': 'rabbitmqHost', 'port': 5671,
                                 'heartbeat_interval': 0,
                                 'ssl': True,
                                 'ssl_options':        {'certfile':'client_certificate.pem',
   'keyfile': 'client_key.pem',
   }
   }`

as per the parameters specified in this [link](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.10.0/examples/using_urlparameters.html#example-connection-urls)

Without SSL enabled and using Plain Credentials I am able to connect to rabbitmq server. However, using the above setup, I get the below error in connecting:

> DEBUG:pika.callback:Added: {'callback': >, 'only': None, 'one_shot': False, 'arguments': None}
>   2017-03-10 16:00:23 [pika.callback] DEBUG: Added: {'callback': >, 'only': None, 'one_shot': False, 'arguments': None}
>   DEBUG:pika.callback:Added: {'callback': >, 'only': None, 'one_shot': True, 'arguments': None, 'calls': 1}
>   2017-03-10 16:00:23 [pika.callback] DEBUG: Added: {'callback': >, 'only': None, 'one_shot': True, 'arguments': None, 'calls': 1}
>   INFO:pika.adapters.base_connection:Connecting to rabbitmqSever:5672 with SSL
>   2017-03-10 16:00:23 [pika.adapters.base_connection] INFO: Connecting to rabbitmqSever:5672 with SSL
>   WARNING:pika.adapters.base_connection:Connection to rabbitmqSever:5672 failed: [Errno 336265218] _ssl.c:355: error:140B0002:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:system lib
>   2017-03-10 16:00:23 [pika.adapters.base_connection] WARNING: Connection to rabbitmqSever:5672 failed: [Errno 336265218] _ssl.c:355: error:140B0002:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:system lib
>   WARNING:pika.connection:Could not connect, 0 attempts left
>   2017-03-10 16:00:23 [pika.connection] WARNING: Could not connect, 0 attempts left
>   DEBUG:pika.callback:Processing 0:_on_connection_error
>   2017-03-10 16:00:23 [pika.callback] DEBUG: Processing 0:_on_connection_error
>   DEBUG:pika.callback:Calling > for "0:_on_connection_error"
>   2017-03-10 16:00:23 [pika.callback] DEBUG: Calling > for "0:_on_connection_error"
>   Unhandled error in Deferred:
>   CRITICAL:twisted:Unhandled error in Deferred:
>   2017-03-10 16:00:23 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

**Update**:

If I use `openssl` to connect:

```
openssl s_client -connect server:5671 -cert client_certificate.pem -key client_key.pem
```

I get the following:

`CONNECTED(00000003)
140243320723104:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:795:
no peer certificate available
No client certificate CA names sent
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 295 bytes
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE`

And rabbitmq logs show a connection but from the ssl port 5672, it says connect refused.

Please note: I am connecting to rabbitmq from a `scrapy spider`

Comment: Maybe it comes late, but we had a similar issue. Instead of {ssl_listeners, [5671]}, we wrote {ssl_listeners, [{"0.0.0.0", 5671}]} and it solved our problem. It turned out that RabbitMQ didn't open the port after all without this setting.

Answer (score 2):

It's scary that no one has answered this in 2 years... I got it to work over SSL on the same instance. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57595427/authenticating-rabbitmq-using-externalcredentials/57596906#57596906) but I haven't gotten it to work outisde of the localhost because it seems like despite using SSL it still uses the "guest" user and the guest user doesn't allow connections from outside of localhost.

```
%% -*- mode: erlang -*-

[
 {rabbit,
  [
   {ssl_listeners, [5671]},
   {ssl_options, [{cacertfile,"/home/daudn/tls-gen/basic/result/ca_certificate.pem"},
                  {certfile,"/home/daudn/tls-gen/basic/result/server_certificate.pem"},
                  {keyfile,"/home/daudn/tls-gen/basic/result/server_key.pem"},
                  {verify,verify_none},
                  {fail_if_no_peer_cert,false}]},

   {auth_mechanisms, ['PLAIN', 'EXTERNAL']}


].
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
connectionFactory.getRabbitConnectionFactory().useSslProtocol()
```

Comment: You might want to give some extra details. What is this code doing? How does it solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

if you created the certificates with a password try adding the password to the rabbit config file:
ssl_options.password = password123